# Issue with importing datetime in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, import

I know this is a stupid question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere. I want to extract day and month separately into a variable and later on make few manipulations to them, but when I tried below code I keep getting a error. I tried to do the same thing in many different ways and it worked in shell, but doesn't work in my .py file.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now.month)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/Documents/Python/import time.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
  File "/home/john/Documents/Python/datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    now = datetime.today()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Comment: Your traceback does not match your code example. `today()` is a method for `datetime.date` instead.

Comment: If I'm not using today() why I'm getting the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'today'? I'm very new to Python and I'm finding this importing very confusing.

Comment: Look closely at the traceback. `from datetime import datetime` imported a *different* module from what you expected. Remove or rename the `/home/john/Documents/Python/datetime.py` file..

Comment: Your script file is called `import time.py`; you may want to rename that too. :-)

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid. Thank you very much for the quick reply! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the paths of the errors, It looks like you added a `datetime.py` file which is shadowing (being imported instead of) the builtin `datetime` module.

The take-away is *don't name your modules the same thing that builtin modules are named*